# PyPDF module doesn' t make valid pdf file

Tags: python, file, pdf, pypdf

i'm trying to make some program in python to manipulate my pdf beamer presentations. Professor use on click dynamic transition so one page has several click transitions. I want to print those presentations but i have around 5000 pages. So i want to use just the last click transition page, so i will minimize number of pages to around 500. I'm using PyPDF2 module but it not makes valid pdf file. Here's the code:

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import os,sys

pdful = raw_input("Uneti ime fajla:")
output = PdfFileWriter()
input1 = PdfFileReader(open(pdful, "rb"))

m = []
f = True
print ("Uneti strane koje zelite da zadrzite.String 0 kraj unosa:\n")

while f:
   l = int(raw_input("Uneti broj stranice:"))
   if l == 0:
      f = not f
   else: m.append(l-1)

for i in range(len(m)):
    strana  = input1.getPage(int(m[i]))

    output.addPage(strana)

outputStream = file("Mat8.pdf","wb")
output.write(outputStream)
# string writings are in Serbian, but that's not so important. Program should take input from user: name of file to manipulate, and pages that should copy.
```

Comment: Do not use `file` to open a file, use the `open` function instead. Also you probably want to close the output file to be sure that the writes were completed by putting `outputStream.close()` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader` pyPdf is discontinued already and is succeeded by PyPDF2. I am not sure about Python 2, but in Python 3 you should `import PyPDF2`.

1. No need to `import os, sys`. However, you can call `python3 xyz.py some_arg` in bash if you did use `sys.argv`. This way `sys.argv[1] == some_arg`
2. I would prefer using maps instead, as long as you don't need to read input line by line. For example,

   ```
   print ("Uneti strane koje zelite da zadrzite.String 0 kraj unosa:\n")
   m = map (lambda x: int(x) - 1, raw_input("Uneti broj stranice:").split())
   ```
3. Instead of the `while` loop. Also, iterate over objects instead of indices.

   ```
   for page_number in m:
       strana = input1.getPage(page_number)
       output.addPage(strana)
   ```
4. Finally, use `with` to enclose file operations. Python will automatically handle closing of the file, lest you forget to do so.

   ```
   with open (pdful, 'wb') as outputStream:
       output.write(outputStream)
   ```

Comment: i am very new to python, but when this map function will end?

Comment: `split` turns `"alpha beta gamma"` into `["alpha","beta","gamma"]`. `map` applies the `lambda` onto every element of the spliced input. As `input` works on one line only, `map` only applies to that line of input.